# What's the correct way to use allocators for polymorphic types?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, c++17, allocator

I am adding custom memory allocators to a system, and am trying to do this correctly through the `Allocator` concept, but I have run into a bit of an uncertainty when reaching a point where the type of the allocated component has been erased.

```
class Pimpl_interface {
public:
  virtual ~Pimpl_interface() {}
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class Pimpl : public Pimpl_interface {
public:
  void foo() override {}
};

template<typename Alloc = std::allocator<void>>
class MyType : public Alloc {
  Pimpl_interface * pimpl_ = nullptr;
public:  
  MyType(const Alloc& alloc) : Alloc(alloc) {}

  ~MyType() {
    if(pimpl_) {
      pimpl_->~Pimpl_interface();
      // What do I put here ?????
    }
  }

  template<typename T>
  void bar() {
    using real_alloc_t = typename Alloc::template rebind<Pimpl<T>>::other;
    real_alloc_t alloc(*static_cast<Alloc*>(this));
    Pimpl<T>* ptr = alloc.allocate(1);
    try {
      pimpl_ = new(&ptr) Pimpl<T>();
    }
    catch(...) {
      alloc.deallocate(ptr, 1);
      throw;
    }
  }
};
```

At a glance, it seems the thing to do is rebind `Alloc` to `Pimpl_interface`, and hope that this does the right thing. I know that this will work fine with `std::allocator`, but is this something that user allocators are supposed to support for all rebindable allocator types?

As a worst-case scenario, I can take a duck-typed `malloc/free`-like allocator object instead, but I'd rather try and follow the standard library if I can.

Comment: Note `std::shared_ptr` implementations essentially need to store the allocator object along with the reference-counted control block, not directly in the `shared_ptr`...

Answer (score 0):

I feel like there's a lot going on. It looks like at the core of things, you want to use alternative allocators safely (in particularly, in a PImpl'd class). To me, the smallest useful piece of that requirement is to make an allocator work with `std::unique_ptr`. If I follow correctly, I think you'll want it to be a `std::unique_ptr<T, std::function<void(T*)>>`.
Similarly, it looks like `std::allocate_shared` may be close enough to what you want. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/allocate_shared

Is this what you need?:

```
template<typename Alloc = std::allocator<void>>
class MyType {
  Alloc alloc_;
  std::shared_ptr<Pimpl_interface> pimpl_ = nullptr;
public:  
  MyType(const Alloc& alloc) : Alloc(alloc) {}

  ~MyType() {} // shared_ptr ftw.

  template<typename T>
  void bar() {
    using real_alloc_t = typename Alloc::template rebind<Pimpl<T>>::other;
    real_alloc_t alloc(alloc_);
    pimpl_ = std::allocate_shared<Pimpl<T>>(alloc);
  }
};
```

(I dropped the inheritance from `Alloc` 'cause that seemed dicy.)

Comment: Instead of using a `std::function`, why not look into something using `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator`.

Comment: Well, my example is a MCVE, I intentionally did not use a unique_ptr because I wanted to isolate the question around the allocator semantics by themselves in isolation to how they interact with the rest of the standard library.

Comment: And the inheritance is to leverage empty base optimization, which is common and important with allocators, since they are often stateless.

Comment: Finally, no this doesn't answer my question. It just kicks the can down the road to shared_ptr.

Comment: I'm not an expert at allocators, but I think `std::allocate_shared` automagically fills out the d'tor, so while not a direct answer, I think it obviates your question "What do I put here ?????"

Comment: Note:  you need to be careful using `std::function` as a deleter, as move construction/assignment for `function` can throw exceptions.  (C++20 will make `function` move construction `noexcept`, but I wasn't able to get the same for move assignment).